# Cannot redirect to next page on clicking of a submit button in cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to cakephp i have a form which is a login form on clicking of a login form submit button the page does'nt redirect. It returns to the same page i.e. Login page. The problem is removed when i remove LoginAction from AppController. My code is as follows:

> index.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Login', array('url' => array('controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'dashboard'))); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('username'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->submit('Login', array('class' => 'button')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

> AppController.php

```
 $this->loadComponent('Auth',['loginAction' => [
                        'controller' => 'Login',
                        'action' => 'index'
                     ],'authenticate' => [
                          'Form' => [
                           'userModel' => 'Login', // Added This
                            'fields' => [
                              'username' => 'username',
                              'password' => 'password',
                             ]
                           ]
                     ],'loginRedirect' => [
                         'controller' => 'Post',
                         'action' => 'dashboard'
                     ],
                ]);
```

> LoginController.php

```
public function dashboard()
{
    echo "sample msg";
    $this->render('dashboard');
}


  public function login(){
   if($this->request->is('post')){
     $user=$this->Auth->identify();
     if($user) {
     $this->Auth->setUser($user);
     return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Post']);
     }
     $this->Flash->error('Incorrect Login');
       }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is related with redirecting just add this in respective controller:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Auth->allow(['dashboard']); // your actions list
}
```

You need to allow actions if you need to access them just before login get success.

Comment: But i get the same login page after clicking on the submit button. I think the problem is in AppController.php

Comment: where is your login action ? is it belong to Users controller ?

Comment: There is no user controller, it belongs to login controller, but it still does not work if i call dashboard action which simply renders another view.

Comment: you mean you have login controller ?

Comment: yes, and for one second if i forget login action in login controller there is dashboard action which should work when i click on submit button but that also not working that is for only testing purpose.

Comment: If i am making LoginAction to blank then it is redirecting properly, but LoginAction should also be there in AppController

Comment: Okey i just got what you are looking for..see the updated answer.